# Excel: Given a cell in column B as input, how could I find out the lowest cell of A which B > A?

Tags: excel, count, formula

I have an excel sheet, which value of column A >= B in the same row.

I would like to know given a cell in column B, how could I find out the lowest cell of A which B > A? (It should return a cell address but not the value)

For example, the following shows cells from A1 to B7 in a sheet:

```
    A  B
   ------
1 | 1  1
2 | 3  2
3 | 5  3
4 | 7  4
5 | 9  5
6 | 10 6
7 | 15 10
```

Now I would like to input B6, then it should return A3 (since 6 > 5)
Another example, if I input B7, then it should return A5 (since 10 > 9)

Is there any approach (or similar approach) by using excel formula? Or should I use other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input value is in cell E1, and your return value is in cell E2 (as shown in below image), then you can use this formula in cell E2:

```
=IF(E1="","",INDEX(A1:A7,MAX(1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A7>=E1,),0)-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Can I know which cell does the value refers to? I mean, I want the result to be a cell (like A3) but not a value

Comment: Great answer. @user3545752 to get address, wrap INDEX with CELL. Like this, CELL(“address“, INDEX(A1:A7,MAX(1,M ATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:A7>=E1,),0)-1)))

Answer (score 1):

Input Cell E1  (enter the address from column B here)

```
F1:  =ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT(E1)>ColA),ROW(ColA)),1,4)
```

Given your data, if you enter B6 in E1, A3 will show in F1